# How to Get media for webRTC in webview?

Tags: android, webview, webrtc, easyrtc

I Run an app that let you start voice chat with webRTC (it based in easyRTC)
when I call my page from android browser it ask for get media resource and then start chat ...
[image]
However when I Call my webpage in android webview does not get request for media , the Error : Failed to get access to local media Error code was permissionDeniedError !

in manifest i add these permissions :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

I know it just support in android L or later  [webview in android L](https://gauntface.com/blog/2014/07/02/webview-in-the-developer-preview-of-l)
and I test the sample in that Link ! But I can not run it !

Answer (score 2):

Try to add this in your Manifest file:

```
 <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />
```